# Mudar conteúdo de uma página com base no <a> que o chamou

Tags: javascript, html5

Tenho um arquivo `index.html` com várias tags `<a>` o `href` de todas elas apontam para o mesmo arquivo, `detalhe.html`. Nesse arquivo `detalhe.html` eu tenho tags de `<image>`, `<ul><li>`, `<iframe>`, `<h3>`, etc.

A questão é que o conteúdo dessas tags devem ser dinâmicos, ou seja, dependendo de qual tag `<a>` do arquivo `index.html` foi clicado, o conteúdo de `detalhe.html` deve ser diferente. Imaginem uma lista de filmes, clicando em cada filme abre o arquivo `detalhe.html` que contem os detalhes daquele filme (Gênero, Duração, Diretor, Trailer, etc.).

Eu sei que para modificar um elemento o caminho é `getElementById` mas como fazer isso com base na tag `<a>` que chamou o arquivo HTML?

Comment: Será necessário alterar o href dos seus links definindo , por exemplo, o fragmento: `detalhe.html#genero`. Assim, na página de detalhe, basta verificar o valor de `window.location.hash` e mostrar o respectivo conteúdo.

Comment: Você poderia deixar um exemplo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solução:

```
var img_capa;
var h2_titulo;
var li_lancamento;
var li_duracao;
var li_direcao;
var li_gerero;
var p_sinopse;
var iframe_video;

if (typeof window.location.hash != "undefined" && window.location.hash == "#logan"){
    img_capa = "img/logan.jpg";
    h2_titulo = "Logan";
    li_lancamento = "2017";
    li_duracao = "2h: 17min";
    li_direcao = "James";
    li_gerero = "Ação";
    p_sinopse = "Em 2024, os mutantes estão em franco declínio, e as pessoas não sabem o real motivo. Uma organização está transformando as crianças mutantes em verdadeiras assassinas. Wolverine, cansado de tudo e a pedido de um cada vez mais enfraquecido Professor Xavier, precisa proteger a jovem e poderosa Laura Kinney, conhecida como X-23. Enquanto isso, o vilão Nathaniel Essex amplia seu projeto de destruição."
    iframe_video = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/RWSuAC9CYxo"
}

document.getElementById("capa").src = img_capa;
```

No exemplo estou mudando apenas a imagem da tag `<img>` mas o principio para as demais tags é o mesmo. Para os demais filmes, basta criar as clausulas `else if` para os demais filmes.

O fragmento que o colega se refere no comentário é passado dessa maneira:

```
<a href="detalhe.html#logan" class="btn btn-danger" role="button">Detalhes</a>
```